# Adding MPI path requirement for using NFS sharing folder in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, directory, sharing, nfs, mpich

I am a newbie that try to build parallel computing environment using `MPICH`.
I have four virtual computer, 1 master and 3 helper.
I make a `NFS shared folder` in the master computer and install the `MPICH` in it.
I mount that folder in the 3 helper computer.
I had do a lot of thing (`ssh, folder permission, single user`).
I can run the `mpiexec` in the master computer without parallel computation (master only).
I can make a text file in the master computer and edit it in the helper computer.

But

When I try to elaborate the helper computer (helper 1,2,3), I got an error like this:

```
-bash /mirror/mpich2/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy: No such file or directory
(3 same lines)
```

When I try to run the mpiexec in the help computer (helper 1 only), I got an error like this:

```
-bash /mirror/mpich2/bin/mpiexec: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody gime me a clue for the reason why, please? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for editing, Youbaraj Sharma! Do you Know someone who can answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Yes, Yeah! Finally! I found the particular solution (at least it works in my case).

I do not know which one is the structured solution, because I was following a lot of advise from many discussions.

Starting from, making sure that all the master and helper computer have single mpi user, making sure that the nfs shared folder has 777 permission and owned by mpi user, adding the mpi bin path to the system, and so on.

However, I do have an alibi that the main solution is to install libc6-dev-i386 in all helper computer, by running this command in all of them:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

And now I can run the cpi program (attached in MPICH-3.0.4 folder) in 4 of those machine in parallel.

For your information, I am using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS for the master computer and Ubuntu mini 13.10 for the helper computer. I make all of it inside VirtualBox 4.3.2.

Thank you very much and good luck for you all!